# Docker Swarm does not create container

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper, docker-swarm

I'm trying to create 3 zookeeper services in my docker swarm. However only managed to create 2 of the 3 containers:

docker ps -a returns:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
2c883f9148ff        hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp   fabric_zookeeper1.1.td4wpq2t9uj5yjnw0q76gsqi0
068ef5d9075b        hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp   fabric_zookeeper2.1.u3zr2o8lifcncjo6g2u2yqhwu
```

docker network ls return:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
0e17f2cd7e8d        bridge              bridge              local
4f78c376719f        docker_gwbridge     bridge              local
djds6rgg0pqc        fabric              overlay             swarm
o1es27fz05i1        fabric_net          overlay             swarm
2f99d3b30b86        host                host                local
ls05jfjuekg0        ingress             overlay             swarm
e7d8a3ff8bb2        net_blockcord       bridge              local
42ec3d9a4f1b        none                null                local
```

docker network inspect fabric_net return:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "fabric_net",
        "Id": "o1es27fz05i1g9cjrq5nvv0ok",
        "Created": "2018-10-26T07:41:49.436040523Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.6.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.6.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "068ef5d9075bc9c61b313b97cfbb36189401bc4eb72258b4346f659add5b3a0a": {
                "Name": "fabric_zookeeper2.1.u3zr2o8lifcncjo6g2u2yqhwu",
                "EndpointID": "3274a8bc693c742a0acedd786174a1c7ed4c2843cd28a6ff9140a2e977059657",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:06:11",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.6.17/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "2c883f9148ff3b53228e8d02a8bd60db754cd2677155307e5db31f426e356223": {
                "Name": "fabric_zookeeper1.1.td4wpq2t9uj5yjnw0q76gsqi0",
                "EndpointID": "f58c3c303a6f2fe22ba410e0881f67ce002cbfc5e0afe9cd1104f7f11e2c6ecf",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:06:15",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.6.21/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "lb-fabric_net": {
                "Name": "fabric_net-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "d70a81ad2631c3b76feac7484599e0715c9b901d2ed72153a38105b236b4c882",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:06:02",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.6.2/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4103"
        },
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.stack.namespace": "fabric"
        },
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "a2beaca62ca3",
                "IP": "10.0.0.5"
            },
            {
                "Name": "fa12393e1d65",
                "IP": "137.116.149.79"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

With my container showing only 2 of my 3 zookeepers

I first create an overlay network

```
docker network create --attachable --driver overlay fabric
```

and ran the below docker compose file using command:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose-zookeeper.yaml fabric
```

docker-compose-zookeeper.yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '3'

networks:
  net:
services:
  zookeeper0:
        hostname: zookeeper0.example.com
        image: hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper
        ports:
            - 2181
            - 2888
            - 3888
        environment:
            - ZOO_MY_ID=1
            - ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888 server.2=zookeeper1:2888:3888 server.3=zookeeper2:2888:3888
        networks:
          - net

  zookeeper1:
        hostname: zookeeper1.example.com
        image: hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper
        ports:
            - 2181
            - 2888
            - 3888
        environment:
            - ZOO_MY_ID=2
            - ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=zookeeper0:2888:3888 server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888 server.3=zookeeper2:2888:3888
        networks:
          - net

  zookeeper2:
        hostname: zookeeper2.example.com
        image: hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper
        ports:
            - 2181
            - 2888
            - 3888
        environment:
            - ZOO_MY_ID=3
            - ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=zookeeper0:2888:3888 server.2=zookeeper1:2888:3888 server.3=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
        networks:
          - net
```

docker info:

```
Containers: 2
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 15
Server Version: 18.06.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: x8mooygnt8mzruof5c5d3p0vp
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: vmqqjuwztz3sraag3e8dgpqbl
 Managers: 2
 Nodes: 2
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 10
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: 10.0.0.5
 Manager Addresses:
  137.116.149.79:2377
  168.63.239.163:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e
runc version: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-1023-azure
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.853GiB
Name: blockcord-staging2
ID: UT5F:4ZFW:4PRT:LGFS:JIV4:3YAD:DK5I:BIYL:FU6P:ZFEB:3OD3:U5EX
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the container was created in my other nodes. But my container wasnt able to resolve address of the service

Comment: Hello, could you give more information on how did you fix it? Did you edit your .yml or made a different swarm init argument?

Comment: you can set the node id in the yml file to the node id in which you want your container to be created in